# yii2 dynamic-form wbraganca call javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I have read some articles about yii2 dynamic-form and javascript function. The solution given by InsaneSkull is perfect. But i have one question.
example :
i'm using dynamic-form from wbraganca and trying to call function *onchange event* (javascript). My code like this

```
    <?= $form->field($detail, "[{$i}]qty")->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),
[
        'clientOptions' => [
                'alias' => 'numeric',
                'groupSeparator' => ',',
                'digits' => 0,
                'autoGroup' => true,
                'removeMaskOnSubmit' => true,
                'rightAlign' => false,                                                                  
        ],
        'options' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'onchange' => 'Info($(this))',                                                                  
        ]                                                               
]) ?>
```

First, i try to register Info function like below

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS

function Info(item){
   var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");        
   alert(index);        
};

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

It gave error because Info function not defined yet.

Second, I registered in AppAsset and it worked.

My question : what is the differences? *(I think it was the scope).
How to define the function beside register in AppAsset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where dou you register above script? If in view after use widget, default position at which JS is register is POS_READY `public void registerJs ( $js, $position = self::POS_READY, $key = null )` Try to use position POS_BEGIN or POS_HEAD if you want to put the script after use widget. Otherwise You can override widget class and put this script into `init` method of the widget which is execute before `run` method rendered widget.

Comment: Also you can register event change handler in your script, not in widget options. Try to use $('.form-control').on('change', Info)

Comment: You welcome. Because when you define change handler in widget options, widget render this handler before script with your function.